# universal motor wiring help needed

Tags: universal-motor

I have a NOS universal ac/dc motor and don't know how to wire it. The motor has 4 unmarked leads. Two black, one red and one white. The motor label is marked VOLTS 115, CYCLES 60, AMPS. 1.0, SER. 12V39607, 900 rpm, thermally protected. Can someone provide the proper the wiring info?

Thanks,
Henry Rancourt

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to be a universal AC/DC motor. It appears to be a single-phase AC motor made by the Universal Motor Co. If it doesn’t have a capacitor attached to it, it probably needs one.

Comment: If you can not find published info for the motor, it is going to be difficult to use it. Start by measuring the resistance from each wire to every other wire. What is printed at the left edge of the nameplate?

Comment: The left side of the label is marked VOLTS 115, CYCLES 60, Amps. 1.0, SER. 12V39067. And I've seen ads for universal motors and I don't recall seeing capacitors on them. Also Universal Electric Company went out of business some years ago.

Comment: I think you’re conflating the manufacturer’Universal Electric’ with the term ‘universal motor’. A universal motor will have brushes and a commutator. That fact that the nameplate on your motor has a Hz rating suggests that it might not be a universal motor, thus the need for a capacitor.

Comment: Why would the plate have 12V39607?

Comment: I have learned that SER. means serial number not service and that it is an induction motor. And the 4  leads are black, blue, red and white. Does anyone know how to connect this to a 3 prong cable?

Comment: I've learned it is a multi-speed shaded pole fan motor with 4 leads. White wire (L1) from source goes to white motor lead. Hot wire (L2) form source goes to black for high speed, blue is medium sped and red is low speed. My question now is should the unused leads be joined or not?

Comment: The unused leads should not be joined.

Comment: Speed control for a motor like that is highly dependent on the load. With no load, the motor will operate close to 900 RPM regardless of speed connection. With a load other than a fan or centrifugal pump, the motor will not perform very well. It is likely to stall if the reduced speed connections are used and may not start with any connection except when only lightly loaded.

Comment: The motor runs quietly and smoothly and does not require a capacitor. With no load it is easy to discern the three different speeds. Calculated hp is .1, torque is 1.217Nm  and power factor is .65 so it would be a good fit with a watchmakers lathe except for one characteristic I just became aware of. Shaded pole motors run very hot and require constant air flow. I don't want to add a fan to my setup so will be looking for a different motor type.